# Заполнить свойство через цикл

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Получаю массив со значениями. Нужно все значения вывести на график. Подскажите, как все эти значения вывести?

```
 $.ajax({

        dataType: "json", // Тип данных, который ожидаем получить
        type: "POST",
        url: "/web/report/count-registration",
        data: {"value": value, "query": "registration", _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()},
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            var years = result.map(function(year) {
                return year;
            });
            var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("popChartRegistration"), {
                    type: "bar",
                    data: {
                        labels: [result[0], date.getFullYear()],
                        datasets:
                            [{
                                label: ["Всего жителей"],
                                data: ["321", "222", "23", "1", "453", "157", "32", "22", "160", "533", "11", "27", "42", "22", "4", "8", "2", "128", "320", "300", "200", "160", result],
                            }]
                    },
                    options: chartOptions
                })
            ;
        },
```

Нужные значения хранятся в `result`. Пробовал через `result.map()`, но что-то не совсем понял как правильно использовать функцию `map`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данные в переменной `result`. Года передаю в массиве `date`, данные после годов передаю в массиве `counts`.

Comment: Какого вида данные у вас хранятся в `result`?

Comment: 2 строковых массива. Но для начала достаточно вывести один.

Comment: Ну вы в вопросе покажите ваши данные. Как можно рассказать, как сделать, не видя из чего сделать?

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: Скриншот особо не поможет... Приведите данные в виде `json`. Вместо `alert` используйте `console.log`.

Comment: Подойдёт в таком виде?

Answer (score 1):

Пример создания графика с данными вида `[[...],[...]]`.

```js
//Здесь эмулиурем данные от сервера
var result = [];
var years = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  years.push(1994 + i);
}
var counts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  counts.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
}
result.push(years);
result.push(counts);

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'bar',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: result[0], //Года
    datasets: [{
      label: "Всего жителей",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: result[1], //Количество
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Мне нужно вывести все значения в ряд. Чтобы каждый столбец на графике был привязан к году.

Comment: @Андрей для этого скажите, какой библиотекой для построения графиков пользуетесь.

Comment: Chart.js. Я сейчас вывожу все значения так: result[0][0], но во-первых это бред, во вторых, если мы  не будем знать сколько значений внутри, то уже не сможем так вывести.

Comment: @Андрей Посмотрите, я обновил ответ.

Comment: counts и result - это полученные данные с сервера?

Comment: @Андрей `result` - полученные данные с сервера, в формате, показанном вами в вопросе. Что бы составить ответ я просил у вас предоставить данные в *JSON* формате, а не скриншотом. Поэтому пришлось создавать данные самому.